In SQL how to find the days are continuous in different leave request and i need to combine as a single request
SELECT
   LT.Reques_id,
   LT.LeaveFromdate, 
   LT.LeaveTodate   
FROM LeaveTbl LT   
JOIN LeaveTbl_detail LTD ON LT.Request_id = LTD.Request_id

I am getting the result as 3 individual rows for 3 unique requests:

But I need to get a single row for continuous request like this:


A [mcve] is supposed to include both sample table data and the expected result - all as properly formatted text (no images, no links.) Be sure to have at different cases in your sample data (no leave at all, one leave, and two separate leaves).

Supporting holes in the request's dates:
with data(colleague, leavefrom, leaveto)as (
    select 'John', date '2023-12-01', date '2023-12-15' from dual union all
    select 'John', date '2023-12-17', date '2023-12-21' from dual union all

    select 'Helena', date '2023-12-05', date '2023-12-9' from dual union all
    select 'Helena', date '2023-12-20', date '2023-12-29' from dual union all

    select 'John', date '2024-01-01', date '2024-01-01' from dual union all
    select 'John', date '2024-01-02', date '2024-01-02' from dual union all
    select 'John', date '2024-01-03', date '2024-01-05' from dual union all
    
    select 'John', date '2024-02-01', date '2024-02-01' from dual union all
    select 'John', date '2024-02-02', date '2024-02-04' from dual union all
    select 'John', date '2024-02-03', date '2024-02-05' from dual -- union all
)
select d.colleague, 
    min(leavefrom) as from_dat, 
    max(leaveto) as to_dat
from (
    select d.*, 
        sum(case when overlaps is null then 1 end) over(partition by colleague order by leavefrom, leaveto) as grp
    from (
        select d.*, 
            case when leavefrom <= 1+lag(leaveto,1) over(partition by colleague order by leavefrom, leaveto) then 1 end as overlaps
        from data d
    ) d
) d
group by d.colleague, d.grp
;


Helena  05/12/23    09/12/23
Helena  20/12/23    29/12/23
John    01/12/23    15/12/23
John    17/12/23    21/12/23
John    01/01/24    05/01/24
John    01/02/24    05/02/24

Or if your DB supports match_recognize:
select * from data
match_recognize (
    partition by colleague
    order by leavefrom, leaveto
    measures first(leavefrom) as from_dat, max(leaveto) as to_dat
    pattern( overlap* strt )
    define
        overlap as leaveto+1 >= next(leavefrom)
)
;


thanks,  i tried your code i am getting Operand type clash error
" Operand type clash : date is incompatible with int" while calculating the overlaps case when [Time Off Start Date] <= 1+lag([Time Off End Date],1) over(partition by colleague order by [Time Off Start Date], [Time Off End Date]) then 1 end as overlaps

ORACLE supports date arithmetic on DATE, you have to replace with the specific function of your DB to add 1 day.

DATEADD(day, 1, LAG(...) OVER(PARTITION ...))

Great! Its working as expected, Many Thanks
